# How to activate secure cookies in Wildfly?

Tags: java, servlets, cookies, wildfly, wildfly-8

I’m trying to add the secure flag to my cookies for a web app in Wildfly (version 8.2). In [the documentation page of the servlet container settings](http://wildscribe.github.io/Wildfly/8.2.0.Final/subsystem/undertow/servlet-container/index.html) you’ll find that the children of the “servlet-container” are:

1. jsp
2. persistent-sessions
3. session-cookie
4. websockets

However I only have *jsp* and *websockets*. How do I access the session-cookie settings? If I can’t, how to I add the secure flag to my cookies?

**UPDATE**: I can’t access the web.xml files inside the wars, only wildfly configuration files.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try following command via jboss-cli:

```
/subsystem=undertow/servlet-container=default/setting=session-cookie:add(http-only=true,secure=true)
```

or in your standalone.xml:

```
<servlet-container name="default">
    <session-cookie http-only="true" secure="true"/>
    <jsp-config/>
</servlet-container>
```

ref: http://wildscribe.github.io/Wildfly/8.2.0.Final/subsystem/undertow/servlet-container/setting/session-cookie/index.html

Comment: which is the best approach adding in standalone.xml: or web.xml?

Answer (score 6):

One can easily configure the **secure** flag and it's security cousin **http-only** flag by adding the following to your web.xml.

```
    <session-config>
      <cookie-config>
        <http-only>true</http-only>
        <secure>true</secure>
      </cookie-config>
    </session-config>
```

Comment: Also set `<tracking-mode>COOKIE</tracking-mode>` to avoid appending to url

Comment: I have no power over the developer team.